# Get tag content

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have the following xml structure

```
<description>
    <category id="HBLMENEURSPALGA" order="83500">Spa. Handball Liga Asobal
    </category>
    AMAYA Sport San Antonio - C.BM.Torrevieja
</description>
```

And with the following code I get

> Spa. Handball Liga Asobal AMAYA Sport
>   San Antonio - C.BM.Torrevieja

but I want just this:

> AMAYA Sport San Antonio -
>   C.BM.Torrevieja

```
$teams  =   $game->getElementsByTagName("description");
               foreach ($teams as $team)
               {
                     $info      =   $team->nodeValue;
               }
```

Comment: Sorry to point it out, but thats not valid XML any parser will exit out with an error.  The text your after has to be in a seperate <tag> for this to be valid.  Are you sure this is the exact XML your using.

Comment: @toby... perfectly valid XML..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point to the right node. This node you're pointing to is actually the whole `description` node, while you need to point to the (implicit) text node containing the string you want.

Solution (provided the string always comes last):

```
$teams = $xml->getElementsByTagName("description");
foreach ($teams as $team)
{
    $info = $team->lastChild->nodeValue;
    echo "info: $info\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the `childNodes` of the `$team` and check if the `nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE`

```
foreach ($teams as $team)
  {
    foreach($team->childNodes as $child)
      {
         if ($child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE && trim($child->nodeValue) != '')
           {
             $info = $child->nodeValue;
             break;
           }
      }
  }
```

this is beacuse text is also a node (*thus the need to loop the childNodes*), that has a `nodeType` value of `XML_TEXT_NODE` (3)

I am also checking the `nodeValue` to be non-empty because white-space between nodes can also be treated as textNodes..